# Dropdown menu with different links for each page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a ruby/rails app - ruby v 2.1.4, Rails v4.1.14

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but can't seem to hack this out. I'm still fairly new to Ruby/Rails as I'm sure will be obvious.

My app has a JS dropdown menu on the header bar that takes an unordered list for its items. Example:

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li><a href="#">EDIT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DELETE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CLONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">EXPORT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HIDE COMMENTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PERMISSIONS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SHOW DETAIL</a></li>
      <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
    </ul>
```

I want the list of items in the menu to change on every page. For example, the "Item view" page may have all of the above, but the "Item Edit" page has 4 additional options, and the "Categories" page only has "Edit", "Delete", and "Clone."

The header bar has its own partial, called from application.erb before the `<%= yield %>`, so the header bar (and menu) are on every page. It's only the menu **options** that need to change on each page.

My first idea for how to do this was:

1. Define an array (@menulinks) on each individual page. The array defines what's in the menu, like so "link_text => url_path":

   ```
   @menulinks = {'Edit' => '/item/edit/', 'Delete' => '/item/delete/' etc etc}
   ```
2. Pass the array into the UL that controls the menu, in the header bar partial, like so:

   ```
   %ul.dropdown-menu
     - @menulinks.each do |key, value|
     %li= link_to key, value
   ```

But there's a catch, because the links are more complicated (I need to call methods using link_to, I think). So the links needed look more like this (for "delete"):

```
   = link_to "Delete", item_path(@item), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this item?"}
```

How could I pass something like that into the UL? Can the link part be escaped in such a way that rails parses it correctly in the UL?

Or am I completely over-thinking this and there's a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `before_filter` to set a helper method that will be used to return your list of links. You could even set a default in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :setup_menu_links

  protected

  def setup_menu_links
    @menu_link_list = :default_menu_links
  end

end

class OtherController < ApplicationController

  protected

  def setup_menu_links
    @menu_link_list = :other_menu_links
  end
end
```

You can define your list of menu links in helpers:

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def default_menu_links
    [
      link_to('First item', ...),
      link_to('Second item', ...)
    ]
  end
end

class OtherHelper
  def other_menu_links
    [
      link_to('Other first', ...),
      link_to('Other second', ...)
    ]
  end
end
```

Then your menu partial can call the configured method using `send`:

```
%ul.dropdown-menu
  - self.send(@menu_link_list).each do |menu_link|
  %li= menu_link
```

Just an idea.

Comment: Very nice. I like that a lot better than putting all the code in the hamls, as I did (which works, but yours is better).

Answer (score 0):

I was over-thinking this. One solution (maybe not the most elegant, anyone have other ideas?):

In the individual page partials, define each link in a local variable, like so:

```
    del_link = link_to "Delete", item_path(@item), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}
    edit_link = link_to "Edit", edit_dashboard_path(@dashboard)
```

Then store these in an array:

```
    @menuitems = [del_link, edit_link]
```

Now, in the header haml containing the menu, run the array into the UL using a loop:

```
    %ul.dropdown-menu
      - @leftmenuitems.each do |link|
        %li= link_to link
```

That seems to work fine.